# Can I standardize a binary dependent variable? and what would be the interpretation of the regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, standardization

I have 3 linear regressions with differently scaled dependent variables and the same independent varibales. I standardized the dependent variables for comparison reasons. The other regression includes a binary dependent variable. I want to run an OLS and not logit/probit so I can compare the results. But can I standardize a binary dependent variable? and if I can, how do I interpret the results-the coeffecients of the predictors?
Thanks

Comment: A binary variable can only take two values.  Even if these are $\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}$ with probability $p$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{p}{1-p}}$ with probability $1-p$ so with  mean $0$ and variance $1$ then there are still only two values, and if your linear regression estimates values larger than the higher of these then you will find interpretation impossible

Comment: And an easy comparison is impossible.  Even without the binary Y comparing the 3 continuous Y fit coefficients is difficult since there is no magic in selecting the standard deviation of Y as a standardizing factor.

Comment: Thank you, I see it would be pointless to do the standardization.

Comment: @Henry This is really close to an answer. Do you want to turn it into one?

Comment: @PeterFlom I was not sure that I really understood the question